# Implement Excel Data into existing Word Document with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i currently have the problem that everytime im trying to open a word document via vba/excel im getting an Application/Object Error. My Idea is that im trying to compare data from two tables and deleting the bad results. After that i want to insert the whole table to the existing word document what im selecting from the selection/opening window.

My Code

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim varDatei As Variant
Dim wordDatei As Variant
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim objSheet As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
Dim extBereich As Variant
Dim intBereich As Variant

Dim appWord As Object

Set intBereich = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A4:A11")

Dim loopStr As Variant
Dim loopStr2 As Variant
Dim found() As Variant
Dim loopInt As Integer
Dim endStr As Variant

Dim extBereich2 As Variant

loopInt = 1
varDatei = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-Dateien (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If varDatei <> False Then
    objExcel.Workbooks.Open varDatei
    Set objSheets = objExcel.Sheets(1)
    objSheets.Activate
    LetzteZeile = objSheets.Cells(objSheets.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Set extBereich = objSheets.Range("B3:B" & LetzteZeile)

    ReDim found(1 To LetzteZeile)
    For Each loopStr In extBereich
        objSheets.Range("F" & loopStr.Row) = "Good"
        objSheets.Cells(loopStr.Row, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        For Each loopStr2 In intBereich
            If (StrComp(loopStr, loopStr2, vbBinaryCompare) = 0) = True Then
                found(loopInt) = objSheets.Range("A" & loopStr.Row)
                loopInt = loopInt + 1
                objSheets.Cells(loopStr.Row, 6) = "Bad"
                objSheets.Cells(loopStr.Row, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Exit For
            End If
        Next loopStr2
    Next loopStr
    loopStr = ""
    If (loopInt <> 1) Then
        endStr = "This is bad:" & vbLf
        For Each loopStr In found
        If (Trim(loopStr & vbNullString) <> vbNullString) Then
            endStr = endStr & loopStr & vbLf
        End If
        Next loopStr
        MsgBox (endStr)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Everythings good")
    End If
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    appWord.DisplayAlerts = False
    Debug.Print ("123")
    Set wordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename("Word-Dateien (*.doc;*.docx;),*.doc;*.docx"))
    wordDoc.Activate
    Debug.Print ("456")
    loopStr = ""
    For Each loopStr In extBereich
        If (objSheets.Cells(loopStr.Row, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3) Then
            objSheets.Range("A" & loopStr.Row & ":" & "E" & loopStr.Row).Delete
        End If
    Next loopStr
    objSheets.Range(Columns(2), Columns(4)).Delete
    objSheets.Range("A3:B" & LetzteZeile).Copy
    appWord.Documents(1).Range.Paste
    With appWord.Documents(1).Tables(1)
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    appWord.PrintOut
    objExcel.Quit
    appWord.Quit
    Set appWord = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Debug.Print loopInt


Else
    MsgBox "Error"
End If

End Sub
```

Maybe someone of you knew whats the problem?

Error Code is 1004 - Application- or object Error

With best regards and thanks for answering

Comment: What's the relation to C++ and VB.NET ?

Comment: my bad sorry, just autoclicked the tags :(

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?

Comment: Line 63: Set wordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename("Word-Dateien (*.doc;*.docx;),*.doc;*.docx"))    Thats where Debugging stops, but 456 is still printed into the console

Comment: I think your trouble lies with `Application.GetOpenFilename` - what is Application? - It is unspecified, i.e. since this is Excel-VBA it refers to the parent Application that hosts the VBA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the line:

```
objSheets.Range(Columns(2), Columns(4)).Delete
```

You need to specify where the columns are, e.g.

```
objSheets.Range(objSheets.Columns(2), objSheets.Columns(4)).Delete
```

---

Comment: No problem! I strongly recommend you use break points(left click on the grey strip next to your code) to find errors like these. Put one at the last line which you know works, then step along with F8 until you encounter the error.